# Disable press animation on Vista/Windows7 touch PC

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, accessibility, cursor

I am using a multi-touch HP PC, and I want to disable the little "blip" cursor animations that happens when you touch the screen.

Does anyone know how to disable this cursor animation and/or the little dot that shows up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open Local Group Policy Editor: Run... gpedit.msc
2. Navigate to User Configuration - Administrative Templates - Windows Components - Tablet PC - Cursor
3. Enable the Turn off pen feedback setting.

Comment: This disables the animation. The dedicated touch cursor (tilted square with short extensions in all four directions) remains visible. As far as I know there is no setting to turn off the distinct touch cursor.

Comment: Windows Starter Edition, Home and Home Premium do not include gpedit.msc. Instructions to install it are in this answer [Windows Starter Edition, Home and Home Premium do not include gpedit, how do I install it?](http://superuser.com/a/1018146)

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 10 i selected show Pointer Trails and it got rid of pointers for most internet sites. The mini pointer remained in the Windows10 start screen when i used touch there and also in apps.  So then i selected show visual feedback and that wiped out all the stupid pointers, but then i had to deal with silly visual feedback.  Should have option for no pointers when using Touchscreen.

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)