# Is there any tool to log create process activity in windows?

Tags: windows, process

For example, process notepad.exe created there should be a log entry in the log file.

Is there any such tool in windows?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Task Manager shows programs that are running - how can I see the ones that have been ended?](http://superuser.com/questions/1036917/task-manager-shows-programs-that-are-running-how-can-i-see-the-ones-that-have)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Process Lasso](https://bitsum.com/processlasso/) fits your needs, plus more powerful features

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Mark Russinovich created the tool [Sysmon](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/sysmon) which logs activity in Windows:

> System Monitor (Sysmon) is a Windows system service and device driver
>   that, once installed on a system, remains resident across system
>   reboots to monitor and log system activity to the Windows event log.
>   It provides detailed information about process creations, network
>   connections, and changes to file creation time.

[image]

Look if this tool is enough and logs the information you need.