# Does Windows 10 log events such as visiting a web page, opening a new browser tab, opening a program, etc?

Tags: event-log

I already checked in Event Viewer but cannot seem to find anything as granular as that, that is, things like opening web brwoser tabs, visiting pages, closing/opening programs, etc. Any suggestion?

Comment: no, not as such. forensics analysis would turn up a great deal of evidence of web use, but there is no single, reliable source for this information using standard tools,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, events only appear there if an operating system component or a program explicitly puts them there. Microsoft has full control of Windows components, so they decide exactly what kind of information from them get into the event logs.

Actions taken inside individual programs, however, are not regulated by the operating system. Windows has no special knowledge of Google Chrome, for example, so it doesn't keep track of what pages the user is viewing; that's Chrome's job. Chrome would have to explicitly tell Windows what to write in the log. To keep records of what users are browsing, you need some kind of web filter or monitoring software. Windows 10 has [child accounts](https://www.thurrott.com/windows/windows-10/5187/inside-microsoft-family-and-windows-10-parental-controls) and Chrome has [supervised users](http://www.howtogeek.com/177958/use-supervised-users-to-set-up-parental-controls-on-a-chromebook-or-just-in-chrome/). There are programs and hardware devices that monitor all web traffic.

To get information on launched processes in the event log, you'll need to [set up process auditing](https://superuser.com/q/1036917/380318). After doing that, you'll get your process information in the Security log.