# How track down application in windows, which pops up shortly and disappears?

Tags: windows-10, process

There is some process or application which starts up at random time, days could pass by, till it pops up. It appears only in the taskbar has an icon which looks like a sun and quickly disappears. I suspect it to be something fishy and want to figure out what it could be.

So far I tried increasing the logging level from windows log management, but did not found anything unusual.

Do you have any suggestions how to hunt that thing down?

I'm running on windows 10.

Comment: Is it possible to make a screen shot to post here?

Comment: You might check the tasks folder, see if any tasks are in there...C:\Windows\Tasks

Comment: @John it is disappearing too fast definitely not enough to make a screenshot, will be trying though

Comment: @Moab there are just couple empty .job files from dropbox, removed them too just to be safe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Option 1

For a quick and easy review you can use [ExecutedProgramList](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/executed_programs_list.html) . Although it's easy to use, it's are not as detailed as the second option (see below) e.g. it won't give you a complete list of programs that have been executed. Alternatively you could use [ProcessMonitor](https://support.malwarebytes.com/docs/DOC-1515).

#### Option 2

If you want to be more thorough you can use Process Tracking Events

If you haven't done so already you need to enable Process Tracking Events in the Windows Security Event Log to start future logging (so you'll have to wait until the pop up comes up the next time).

**How to enable Audit Process Creation**

1. Run gpedit.msc
2. Select "Windows Settings" > "Security Settings" > "Local Policies" > "Audit Policy"

   [image]
3. Right click "Audit process tracking" and select "Properties"
4. Check "Success" and click "OK"

   [image]

**How to use Audit Process Creation**

Once the Process Tracking Events are enabled you can use all process creations and deletions (and failed attempts at same) will appear in the Security log.

To view them, run Event Viewer. In the navigation pane expand the "Windows Logs" sub-tree and click "Security". All the security events will be displayed.

Alternatively the following Powershell commands to examine the events:

Process Start:

```
Get-EventLog Security | Where-Object {$_.EventID -eq 4688} | Format-List
```

Process Stop:

```
Get-EventLog Security | Where-Object {$_.EventID -eq 4689} | Format-List
```

Thanks to DavidPostill you'll find a much more detailed answer [here on superuser](https://superuser.com/a/1036921/201818).

Comment: Found it using Option 2, at the end it happened to be Logitec LogiOptions, probably nothing harmful, but now I know and can sleep

Comment: @Ninius86 glad I could help, thanks for the upvote!

Comment: "Audit Process Creation" location is shown incorrectly in the above post. The post shows the location of "Audit process tracking" instead. "Audit Process Creation" is actually here: Windows Settings > Security Settings > Advanced Audit Policy Configuration > Audit Policies > Detailed Tracking > Audit Process Creation

Comment: @RolandPihlakas maybe incorrectly now, back then there was no "Advanced Audit Policy Configuration" as you can see in the screenshot there was no "Advanced Audit Policy Configuration". Thank you for the addition.