# Did I just completely disable Windows 10 updates by disabling the Windows Update service?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, services

I have a data cap and was trying to disable auto-updates on my laptop to use less data. I went into Services from the control panel and set the Startup Type of Windows Update to *Disabled* by right-clicking it, clicking "Properties", and then choosing *Disabled*.

[image: Screenshot]

Are all Windows updates completely disabled, or am I missing something? I am using the Windows 10 home edition.

Answer (score 2):

Let's see what the Windows Update service's description has to say about this:

> If this service is disabled, users of this computer will not be able to use Windows Update or its automatic updating feature, and programs will not be able to use the Windows Update Agent (WUA) API.

Since you've disabled the service responsible for seeking updates, Windows will no longer be able to update itself. That's a Bad Thing<sup>TM</sup>, because getting security updates is important for the integrity of your system. Optimally, you would change the service state back to Manual and restore the triggers with `sc triggerinfo`, but it's probably easier to just make it Automatic if you've blown away the trigger settings.

Note that while the Windows Update service is responsible for getting the updates, Windows Modules Installer is responsible for installing them. You shouldn't disable Windows Modules Installer because that would break even manual installation of `.msu` update packages.

If network usage is a problem, you should [set up a metered connection](http://www.howtogeek.com/226722/how-when-and-why-to-set-a-connection-as-metered-on-windows-10/). If that's not what you're looking for, you can [limit the bandwidth used by the Background Intelligent Transfer Service](https://superuser.com/q/1039229/380318) even on the Home edition.

Comment: I set my home wifi network as a metered connection already, thinking it would fix the problem, and then my computer still downloaded a whole bunch of updates. I plan to turn it back on whenever I have the bandwith and plan to update. Yes I do understand not having the latest updates can be a security issue, but having the latest updates can also be a stability issue. I understand the risk. Also I haven't touched windows modules, because I am just looking to control when my PC updates, not break updates altogether.

Comment: +1 for user71416's approach.  This is *my* laptop and when/if updates occur needs to be under my control. The auto updates also take way way too long.