# Microsoft Edge Dev Tools grayed out on Windows 10 Home

Tags: windows, windows-10, group-policy, microsoft-edge, developer-tools

as the title suggests I want to facilitate the developer tools of Microsoft Edge browser on Windows 10 Home.

The thing is, that they are grayed out. Neither pressing F12 nor trying to launch them through the menu works (they are grayed out).

My problem is that I don't see any `Turn on/off Developer Tools`-option in `pgedit.msc`

Comment: Windows Starter Edition, Home and Home Premium do not include gpedit.msc. Instructions to install it are in this answer [Windows Starter Edition, Home and Home Premium do not include gpedit, how do I install it?](http://superuser.com/a/1018146)

Comment: @DavidPostill yes, thank you! It's helpful, but just notice that I already mentioned this fact + solution in my question. However I will link to your answer since it's answered on superuser.com if I have more than 10 reps on superuser.com in order to post more than 2 links.

Comment: @tux - A question shouldn't contain the solution, you should submit an answer to your question, that is our community works.  If there is already a question, with an answer that worked, you should simply upvote that existing question and answer not submit a duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows Starter Edition, Home and Home Premium do not include gpedit, how do I install it?](http://superuser.com/questions/1018145/windows-starter-edition-home-and-home-premium-do-not-include-gpedit-how-do-i-i)

Comment: @Ramhound yes I know that. I posted the steps I found out so far.stackexchange expects the OP to share its research. However I did also write that I'm missing the 'Turn on/off Developer Tools'-option! I will turn this into a full answer once I resolved it. In fact it works now like "magic" without me changing the 'Turn on/off Developer Tools'-option so I will post this as an answer

Comment: @Ramhound I suggest to remove the duplicate flag. I'm asking how to enable "developer tools"-option in Microsoft Edge, not how to install gpedit.msc on Windows 10 Home. I may not have expressed myself comprehensible.

Comment: I will not retract my duplicate vote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already did some research and found the following solution on [answers.microsoft.com](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie9-windows_7/f12-does-not-open-developer-tools-nor-is-developer/023f56e4-5755-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5):

- launch `gpedit.msc` located at `%windir%\System32\`
- go to `Computer Configuration` -> `Administrative Templates` -> `Windows Components` -> `Internet Explorer` -> `Toolbars`
- you should see `Turn on/off Developer Tools` click turn on

`pgedit.msc` is not installed on Windows 10 Home by default, so one has to [download](https://www.itechtics.com/?ddownload=18248) it from itechtics.com/or follow this answer https://superuser.com/a/1018146/564432.

- I don't see any Turn on/off Developer Tools-option in pgedit.msc, but after killing the explorer.exe and restarting it with the Taskmanager the developer tools are enabled in Microsoft Edge, so you might try rebooting windows/killing and relaunching explorer.exe.

For some reason I don't even see the Toolbars "folder" when I navigate from Computer Configuration, but only when I start from User Configuration.

Comment: +1 The policy is called "Turn off Developer Tools" and must be set to "Disabled". Other than that, this worked for me.