# Silent version of parental controls for Windows Vista

Tags: windows-vista, uac, parental-controls

This question is in a familial context. The concerned people have only minimal knowledge to use their computer. I can't teach them anything security related.

In order to protect a user to install nasty extensions or drive-by downloads (fake "Java updates", etc..), I use parental controls on these computers with a very restricted list. The problem is that one user just ignores those dialogs (for example, Google Chrome Update won't run if not authorized by an admin), and for some reason, having these dialog open in the background actually makes the laptop overheat (fans start running in high speed after a few seconds after the UAC pops up, and remains open).

Now I'm concerned that instead of wasting my time (amongst other things) by installing malware, he will just damage his laptop by just not closing those dialogs.

Is there a way to just silently block those unauthorized programs, and maybe log those attempts somewhere (if this is not already done) ?

Comment: I'd be more concerned about the overheating in general.  UAC dialogs should not cause overheating.  You have a bigger problem that needs to be addressed.

Comment: And yet this is happening. This is not a powerful laptop. The only other times when it looks like it's overheating is caused by Flash ads. I don't think it's a XY problem, there may be something related to UAC dialogs

Comment: In order to address the overheating issue, you could disable Aero/Glass.

Comment: An adblocker will go a small way to preventing drive-bys.

Comment: The laptop may need cleaning.  Dust in the intake, fan, etc.  Another possibility is that its position is blocking the vents.  Check out http://www.howtogeek.com/67660/how-to-diagnose-and-fix-an-overheating-laptop/ for some tips.

Comment: The laptop will shut itself off long before damage could be done.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some steps you can take:

1. Clean out the computer to reduce risk of overheating
2. Search for "adjust performance and appearance of windows" and open that. Check "Adjust for best performance".
3. Use the Local Group Policy editor to enforce restrictions rather than Parental Controls. If you have Home Premium, you can edit the respective registry keys.

Comment: Windows Starter Edition, Home and Home Premium do not include gpedit.msc. Instructions to install it are in my answer [Windows Starter Edition, Home and Home Premium do not include gpedit, how do I install it?](http://superuser.com/a/1018146)

Comment: "Adjust for best performance" seems to solve the problem. The problem is unrelated to a hardware problem (even if it would look like it). I suspect Windows is somehow doing something else while waiting for the dialog to be taken care of, but who knows.