# converting all shutdown requests to sleep requests

Tags: windows-10, sleep, shutdown

My Windows 10 home desktop computer has a broken power button. I have already had 3 different occasions where I was messing around with cables, power outlets and slightly shifting my PC so the power button just might work and I don't want a 4th time. Since shutdown is not really needed on this machine for now, I want to make it so I can no longer turn this PC off completely. Sleep mode and reboot should still be available, because I can use my peripherals to get out of sleep mode. However, I can't do this for shutdown because my BIOS only has an option to do this for PS/2 devices and PCI devices, neither of which are available to me right now.

I have already changed the power button settings to go to sleep mode instead of shutdown, but I also want the on/off options in my start menu to no longer show the shutdown prompt, if at all possible, just sleep and reboot.

I do not want a user-based solution. I am the only person on this computer and I don't trust myself to pay enough attention to select the right option every time I am done with my computer.

Comment: Shutdown being visible is controlled by a group policy

Comment: @Ramhound I don't think W10 Home has that, though?

Comment: [So modify the relevant registry keys.](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/148605-shut-down-restart-sleep-hibernate-commands-add-remove.html)

Comment: @NateKerkhofs Windows Starter Edition, Home and Home Premium do not include gpedit.msc. Instructions to install it are in my answer [Windows Starter Edition, Home and Home Premium do not include gpedit, how do I install it?](http://superuser.com/a/1018146)

Comment: @DavidPostill - Helpful but not required.  the registry keys that handle this behavior are straight forward.

Comment: @Ramhound <shrug> gpedit has many other uses ...

Comment: i agree, but outside of using a "tool" to do it, just editing the registry seems faster.

Comment: I don't really mind editing the registry manually, I just want a solution.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs - Which is the reason the .reg files come in handy.  I will eventually get around to answering this question later today due to the amount of work required to submit an answer.

Comment: @Ramhound note: I checked that sevenforums post, and that also mentions that the .reg file also removes other options. I JUST want to remove shutdown.

Comment: So open the .reg files, determine which key should be modified, and get rid of the other keys and merge the file.  You are smart I trust you can figure it out