# Windows 10 internet options lock

Tags: windows, windows-10, proxy, blocking

Is there a way to lock Internet Options changes on windows 10?

I set up privoxy to limit internet access to users, but they can still change internet options

Comment: Welcome to Super User. What have you researched or tried so far?

Comment: Are the "users" set up as administrators on the computers in question?

Comment: Hi, there was a way to lock via regedit internet options in windows 7 but it doesn't work anymore, and on windows 10 gpedit.msc is not included.

Comment: @Techie007 users are users :), they are not administrators, i'm trying to limits "Users" account

Comment: *on windows 10 Home edition

Comment: @GodTaxist You can install it. [Windows Starter Edition, Home and Home Premium do not include gpedit, how do I install it?](https://superuser.com/q/1018145)

Comment: @DavidPostill have you tried it? I did, and it's a horrible solution, it doesn't work, not to mention security concerns...

Comment: It has been confirmed as working on Windows 10 by [Moab](https://superuser.com/users/40928/moab) a high rep user on [su]. I trust him when he says that.

Comment: @DavidPostill well, good for you. who cares it is unofficial, adapted, requires troubleshooting, and is hosted on deviantart? I don't think high rep is a way of determining safety, moreover did you try it or are you trusting him on ipse dixit?

Comment: I personally have installed in on Windows 7 Home Premium and it is working fine. I don't have access to other Windows versions to test it. Of course it is entirely up to you whether to install it or not. Nobody else can make that decision for you.