# Make Windows 10 ask to send error report

Tags: windows-10, windows-error-reporting

I currently work on Windows 10 home. In previous windows version (vista/xp I'm certain of), when an application crashed, Windows asked permission to send an error report. An memory dump that is sent along may contain some sensitive information on what you where working at the time of the crash. Now most of the time I don't care that much, I rarely work on sensitive stuff (nope not a prime minister or big CEO), but occasionally I may not want to.

So, is there a way to make window 10 ask before sending a detailed error report?

I'm aware of the 'Diagnostics and Usage data' option in the settings app.

Comment: During custom Windows 10 setup, there is an option to turn off "*Send error and diagnostic information to Microsoft*". It appears you can [turn those things off after the fact](https://www.thurrott.com/windows/windows-10/5337/windows-10-tip-understand-and-configure-privacy-settings), but I can not find any information on causing Windows ask "*before sending a detailed error report*".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, Windows 10 Home don't have any **Group Policy editor** (unfortunately). So the usual way [like this](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/cc709644(v=ws.10).aspx#BKMK_Controlling) is not possible:

> You can control the degree to which Windows Error Reporting prompts
>   for consent before data is sent. This setting is located under either
>   Computer Configuration or User Configuration in **Administrative
>   Templates\Windows Components\Windows Error Reporting\Consent**.

Comment: That is a Windows Vista article. Not so sure it applies to Windows 10.

Comment: The group policy problem on Windows 10 Home is easy enough to solve.

Comment: @Ramhound and how exactly would you get past home lacking group policy?

Comment: You mentioning group policy made me think of searching for the registry keys equivalent to the group policy settings. I found https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb513638(v=vs.85).aspx : seems like the DefaultConsent key should do the trick but it does not work with me :/ (default value was also 4) Some registry settings work though like Disabled.

Comment: [Windows Starter Edition, Home and Home Premium do not include gpedit, how do I install it?](http://superuser.com/questions/1018145/windows-starter-edition-home-and-home-premium-do-not-include-gpedit-how-do-i-i)