# Disable system tray links in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, notification-area

I have a copy of Windows 10 Home which unfortunately is not able to be locked down like Enterprise/Pro or Education versions.  I have some computers that I'm setting up for some students and there is some programs that are allowed on the computers, I want to disable everything else.  To that extent I've implemented a bunch of registry keys and what not to accomplish this but there are a few remaining issues.  The biggest problem right now is that the wifi and battery icon on the systray a) can be right clicked to bring up settings b) if you click them - in Windows 10 it has a little link to go into the settings app for the network or power config which lets you access all the other settings from there.

Obviously I could just remove the icons but I feel like that would be detrimental as you couldn't select a wifi network or see the battery percentage anymore.  I would like to just disable the right click and somehow remove the links but otherwise leave it intact.  Even better if there was just some way to password protect or even disable the settings app.

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: [Windows Starter Edition, Home and Home Premium do not include gpedit, how do I install it?](https://superuser.com/q/1018145)

Comment: Thanks!  That helps with many things although I don't see a way to hide the links from items in the systray still.   Also is there any program like AppLocker?