# How to enable FIPS compliance setting without Local Security Policy on Windows 10 Home?

Tags: windows-10, security-policy

I'm having a problem running some software where a feature doesn't work because the cryptographic algorithm being used isn't FIPS validated. Here's an excerpt of the error indicating that:

> 'X' threw an exception. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: This implementation is not part of the Windows Platform FIPS validated cryptographic algorithms.
>      at System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider..ctor()
>      at ...

Someone recommended I enable FIPS to get around this problem, by going to the Local Security Policy Editor and enabling "System cryptography: Use FIPS compliant algorithms for encryption, hashing, and signing".

After some searching, I'm finding that Windows 10 Home has no Local Security Policy Editor.
(I've tried digging into /system32/, running secpol.msc, digging through Control Panel, but there is no Local or Group Security Policy Editor. [On Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/3fdnu7/help_i_cant_find_my_local_group_policy_editor/ctno989/) someone noted that Windows 10 Home will not have those Policy Editors.)

**Is there a way to enable that FIPS compliance setting without having the Local Policy Editor?** I am the administrator on the machine in question.

Comment: "Is there a way to enable that FIPS compliance setting without having the Local Policy Editor?"  - The only way to do this is to modify a configuration file, and it requires you be an Administrator on the machine, is that the case?

Comment: I am admin on this machine. I'll add that to the Q

Comment: Just to confirm.  You are getting this error because your attempting to compile a project within Visual Studio?  If that isn't the case, then the solution requires, you to manually modify registry key associated with the group policy

Comment: No, its' an Unhandled Exception error I get when trying to use a feature (tapping into Google Maps) in a program that's already been compiled. It had worked in the past, and I'm not sure what changed. I'd like to give this FIPS compliance suggestion a try.

Comment: You should modify the group policy, by using the solution to this question, [Windows Starter Edition, Home and Home Premium do not include gpedit, how do I install it?](http://superuser.com/questions/1018145/windows-starter-edition-home-and-home-premium-do-not-include-gpedit-how-do-i-i).  The answer I have prepared to submit does not apply to your situation.  If Google Maps has a application configuration, you should be able to add the [<enforceFIPSPolicy> Element](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202806(v=vs.110).aspx), to it in order to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply this group policy manually if you want.

> If you wish to do this manually, you can also simply change the
>   registry key
>   HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\FIPSAlgorithmPolicy\Enabled
>   to 1

Source [Alex's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886368/how-to-enable-fips-on-windows-7/13635742#13635742) answer to [How to enable FIPS on windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886368/how-to-enable-fips-on-windows-7)

You can also follow the answer to the question, [Windows Starter Edition, Home and Home Premium do not include gpedit, how do I install it?](https://superuser.com/questions/1018145/windows-starter-edition-home-and-home-premium-do-not-include-gpedit-how-do-i-i), in order to get gpedit.msc to work on Windows 10.

> 1. First download the setup file using following link:
>
>    [Download Group Policy Editor Installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886368/how-to-enable-fips-on-windows-7)
>
>    You'll find the download link in right-side section of the above
>      mentioned page.
> 2. After downloading the ZIP file, extract it using WinRAR or 7-Zip.
> 3. Run the extracted setup.exe file.
>
>    It will install the files and you'll be able to access gpedit.msc
>      command via RUN or Start Menu search box.

Source: [DavidPostill's](https://superuser.com/questions/1018145/windows-starter-edition-home-and-home-premium-do-not-include-gpedit-how-do-i-i/1018146#1018146) answer to [Windows Starter Edition, Home and Home Premium do not include gpedit, how do I install it?](https://superuser.com/questions/1018145/windows-starter-edition-home-and-home-premium-do-not-include-gpedit-how-do-i-i)