# Granting privileges to user on Windows 10 Home

Tags: windows-10, group-policy, privileges

How can I grant privileges (for example, `SeShutdownPrivilege`) to users on Windows 10 Home where is no Group Policy Editor available?

Comment: Add the editor, there is an existing question, with an answer that explains how to do that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows Starter Edition, Home and Home Premium do not include gpedit, how do I install it?](http://superuser.com/questions/1018145/windows-starter-edition-home-and-home-premium-do-not-include-gpedit-how-do-i-i)