# Allow non-administrator users to synchronise time (w32tm /resync)?

Tags: windows, administrator, privileges

The scheduled time synchronisation task does not seem to work, probably due to some kind of privilege issue. Running `w32tm /resync` only works when I run the Command Prompt as `Administrator`.

To be honest, I do not think it can be harmful to let anyone synchronise the time with the correct time (though it might be harmful to let them set the time to an arbitrary value). Can I allow non-administrator users to synchronise time (but possibly, not to an arbitrary value)? This is my personal computer, so my user is the only user and it belongs to the Administrator group, but since it is not actually the `Administrator`, it requires UAC elevation to run the time synchronisation command. I would like to avoid this and be able to synchronise time without fuss.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### I would like to avoid this and be able to synchronise time without fuss.

1. At the Windows Run Prompt - type `gpedit.msc`.
2. This will run the Group Policy Editor.

   Note: Windows Starter Edition, Home and Home Premium do not include gpedit.msc. Instructions to install it are in my question & answer https://superuser.com/a/1018146/337631
3. Drill down and select "User Rights Assignment".
4. In the "Policy" area on the right side right Click "Change the system time" and select "Properties"

   [image]

   [image]
5. Click "Add User or Group", add your user, then click "OK".

Comment: Is this supposed to allow the user to run the time synchronisation command without UAC elevation? My user account already belonged to `Administrators`, and I added my account there as your instructions (also, restarted the PC), but running the command in the Command Prompt still showed 'Access is denied' when the Command Prompt was not as Administrator.

Comment: @DamnVegitables I'm not sure, as I can't test it. I only run as a real admin here. And I use the ntp service to auto sync the time.

Comment: @DamnVegitables I see you've accepted the answer (thanks). Does that mean you have got it working?

Comment: Yes and no. I created a normal user that does not belong to the `Administrators` group, and added it to the allowed list. With that account, I could run the w32tm command without running the Command Prompt as the Administrator. But if I added the account to the `Administrators` group, the w32tm command also showed 'Access is denied' when the Command Prompt was not run as the Administrator. I thought perhaps this was the closest answer I could ever get, and if I do not mark it as the answer now, I may forget to do so later, which is not a polite way to thank your effort.