# gpedit.msc command doesn't exist on windows 10 home premium

Tags: windows-10, gpedit

I tried to execute the command gpedit.msc through the "run program" window, but when i do it i get an error that says the command doesn't exist. I tried to execute the command from the administrator user.
My pc has windows 10 Home premium x64

Comment: The bottom line is that the `gpedit.msc` isn't installed within a Home version of Windows by default.  It is essentially a professional's management tool, and is included in that version accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

The windows 10 home edition does not support gpedit.msc it doesn't have it unlike other editions of windows 10's . But you can follow this link they explains you how to workaround it [here](https://www.itechtics.com/enable-gpedit-windows-10-home/)

Comment: We discourage submitting Link-only answers here at Superuser

Comment: @Ramhound go ahead and make a better answer instead of giving every single person on this side a down vote and a lousy comment

Comment: Elie - There is an answer on SU about this topic already though: https://superuser.com/questions/1018145/windows-starter-edition-home-and-home-premium-do-not-include-gpedit-how-do-i-i. Sometimes links break so link-only answers may not be useful here in the future content wise. I usually quote the important parts of any reference I defer to a link for this specific reason. However, in this case, this question has been asked and answered and confirmed to work with Windows 10 Home edition by many others. Your efforts are appreciated for sure so just keep this in mind a bit moving forward.

Comment: @Elie Improve your answer and I will reverse my vote.  There already is a better answer to the duplicate question so I won't be submitting my own

Comment: at least summarize the content of the link so that your answer is still valid when the link rots [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/230282)