# gpedit.msc - MMC could not create the snap-in

Tags: windows-10, environment-variables, mmc, gpedit

Starting gpedit from start>run>gpedit.msc, the Group Policy Window opens, but I get the following error in the right hand window:

**MMC could not create the snap-in**

I tried these solutions from [a link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_xp-update/gpeditmsc-mmc-could-not-create-the-snap-in/6d558ece-62a1-4953-9a90-606ac56ad946), but nothing change.

OS: Windows 10-64bit

Please help me to get through this.

Comment: Windows 10 Home or Windows 10 Professional?

Comment: @Ramhound Windows 10 Home.

Comment: Windows 10 home by default cannot run the group policy editor. Upgrade to Windows 10 Professional

Comment: Duplicate of: https://superuser.com/questions/1018145/windows-starter-edition-home-and-home-premium-do-not-include-gpedit-how-do-i-i

Comment: What?  What you users and user group you deleted isn't clear.  Please keep your question within the scope of what you originally asked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63493/discussion-between-warda-and-ramhound).

Comment: @Ramhound now GPE is running but I am not having complete options. what's the solution for this?

Comment: Your follow-up question is not clear, but it's also a comment, and I can't answer a comment.

Comment: I am not going to answer your question in chat (nor do I have the capability to do that for another 48 hours due to my current location).  If you have a follow-up question you should submit a question.  You should work on the clarity of this question, because it's not actually clear, if the duplicate answered this question or not.