# Can't disable auto screen dimming on ASUS laptop Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, display, asus-laptop

When I open a dark window like Discord, my laptop's display dims. When I minimize it and open something white, it takes a while for the light to go back up and it gives me a headache.

I've tried setting the Intel-something settings for the battery by disabling some option, but there's no way to disable it for when my laptop is on an adapter. I've heard that there's a DCPolicy-something registry key that I need to change, but that registry key doesn't exist. What should I do?

I have a Windows 10 ASUS laptop X540SC.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Below are three methods which are supposed to disable Adaptive Brightness.
Only one is theoretically required, but I list all three in the order of
their likelihood of working out.

Use the Intel Control Panel to set the
Intel HD Graphics
for the power source `On battery` so as to disable
`Display Power Saving Technology` :

[image]

---

You may also in PC Settings, System, Display,
turn the `Change brightness automatically when lighting changes` to `Off`.

This option should be available if your computer has a light sensor.
If it is missing, check the manufacture's website for the correct driver and/or software package, if Windows 10 support is provided for your computer.

---

Edit also the group policy
`Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Power Management > Energy Saver Settings` and set both policies to `Enabled` at `0%`.

For Windows editions of Starter, Home and Home Premium which do not include
the group policy editor, see the post :
[Windows Starter Edition, Home and Home Premium do not include gpedit, how do I install it?](https://superuser.com/questions/1018145/windows-starter-edition-home-and-home-premium-do-not-include-gpedit-how-do-i-i).

Comment: It worked! Thank you! I had a different interface, but the setting was in Power and I turned it off. It's not in English so I'm not sure how it is really called.

Comment: The Intel Control Panel setting only works partly for me: when I disable the "Display Power Saving Technology" setting, the display still dims once when showing a dark window, but then stays dim, which is very annoying.

Comment: I had to reboot for changes to make effect

Answer (score 2):

Make sure `Enable adaptive brightness` is off for both battery and plugged in.

Find this option in Control Panel -> Power Options -> Change Plan Settings (for your active plan) -> Change advanced power settings -> Display

Comment: It's already off