# Unable to disable auto brightness adjustment on ASUS laptop with Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, laptop, display, asus-laptop

I've tried everything posted in the accepted answer for [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1239674/cant-disable-auto-screen-dimming-on-asus-laptop-windows-10?newreg=68f1d2bf5f5a4a178144af0e506b4206) question and none of the proposed solutions work for me, the screen keeps going dark when I'm on a dark window which is very annoying because I use dark windows for most programs I work with.

Does anyone have any other working solutions for this problem?

Comment: have you tried just changing your power settings? the options in the answer you linked are really only going to be applicable if your laptop uses the same power management software - but you should still be able to right-click the battery icon in your task bar, click "Power Options", "Change Plan Settings" for your selected plan, click "Change advanced power settings", and then go through your settings to see if there's anything dimming your display

Comment: @mael' My system is not in English so if any of the options names sound weird, that's why. If I follow your instructions, the only option under "Display" I see that could be dimming my screen is "Adaptive brightness function" which is turned off for both when the laptop is on power supply and on battery.

Comment: when you say "going dark", what do you mean exactly? are you sure your laptop is actually dimming, or is it just... not as bright as a light-colored screen would be..

Comment: When I'm on a dark window, the brightness slowly starts going down this on itself is unnoticeable but when I go from a dark screen to a light screen (let's say a browser window) it is very noticeable that the screen is much darker than it should be. After I switch to the light window it slowly turns the brightness back up again.

Comment: there is a registry change outlined here you can try: https://superuser.com/questions/994443/brightness-changes-while-adaptive-brightness-is-disabled-in-windows-8-1-10-wit

Comment: This seems to have solved my issue, thank you for your help!

Comment: I'll put it in an answer format so we can mark it as solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a registry solution for this if the power settings GUI didn't help:

> 1. Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>
> 2. Type `regedit` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
> 3. Navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Intel\Display\igfxcui\profiles\media\Brighten Movie` and change `ProcAmpBrightness` to `0`
> 4. Navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Intel\Display\igfxcui\profiles\media\Darken Movie` and change `ProcAmpBrightness` to `0`

Reference: [This solution on superuser](https://superuser.com/a/1053032/952586)