# Asus laptop automatically dims screen when I start a software/game in fullscreen

Tags: windows-10, asus-laptop

My laptop is an ASUS with two GPUs:

- (Integrated) Intel hd graphics 520. I think this manages the monitor.
- (Discrete) Nvidia geforce 940M. For games.
  Both have the latest drivers.

What happens is when I start a game, the screen dims and I am unable to increase the brightness. Some notes:

- The backlight keyboard also acts up. Turns itself on.
- It only occurs in fullscreen mode.
- I have "adaptive brightness" turned off in display settings (I have no adaptive brightness option in power options).
- Some people on other threads mention the "Intel Power Saving technology". I have no such setting in my Intel control panel.

Everything is absolutely fine outside programs. But only when I start games in fullscreen, this happens. It's quite annoying.

I think my issue is the same as this: [Can't disable auto screen dimming on ASUS laptop Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1239674/cant-disable-auto-screen-dimming-on-asus-laptop-windows-10?rq=1)
However I do not see an option to turn off power saving tech in my control panel (Intel command center).

Comment: See if this helps, after doing this dim display settings will show up in Advanced Power Options in Control Panel....https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/108132-add-remove-dim-display-after-power-options-windows.html

Comment: @sarge5544 Are you using the factory-supplied charger, or a third-party charger?\

Comment: @ Moab, Added the option but it did not change anything. Screen still dims when starting games. I think it's some kind of power saving tech but I have no idea how to turn it off.

Comment: @ K7AAY The factory supplied one. Again this only happens when I start a game, so it must be a software issue. I tried tinkering with the Intel and nvidia control panel but everything seems set right. My gut feeling is that its an asus feature or maybe the graphics cards. My laptop model was made for Windows 8 and they installed Windows 10 on it, people report problems with that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable both [Panel Self Refresh (PSR)](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000140857/latitude-12-5285-with-detachable-keyboard-may-develop-internal-display-flickering) and [Display Power Saving Technology](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000135009/lcd-brightness-constantly-changing-with-intel-display-power-setting-enabled#Stop_It) in the Intel  Graphics control center, then reboot and retest.

[Some vendors](https://www.reddit.com/r/MatebookXPro/comments/bp9bso/psa_disable_panel_selfrefresh/) don't implement these advanced features correctly, resulting in similar bugs.

Answer (score -2):

I am struggling with the same. I found out that a part of the problem is the ATK package. If you go to process and disable Hcontrol.exe then your games wont act up.

Are you able to find a solution, knowing the ATK package is part of the cause? I havn't found a real solution yet.

Comment: Patrick - this needs to be worded as an answer to the problem.  If you want to say, "Here is a work-around ..." and "I haven't found the root cause of the problem."  That would be fine.  Or, you can just make point in a comment.  If you fix it, I'll vote it back up.