# how to disable Battery Saver config on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, battery

I want to disable Battery Saver in Battery Settings on Windows 10. Disable means, user cannot control this settings anymore.

I tried some samples, but most of them are how to control(turn on or off) battery saver. What I want is completely disable this setting.

anyone know how to do it? it's okay if I can do it on change registry or powershell command.

[this is battery saver setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvUzl.png)

[I want to make options in red block cannot control like this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQJVw.png)

Comment: You should be able to achieve this with applicable group policy

Comment: @Ramhound how to do this exactly?

Comment: The policies in question are in **Computer Configuration** > **Administrative Templates** > **System** > **Power Management** > **Energy Saver Settings**. Set both policies to Enabled at 0%.

Comment: @bwDraco I could't find it in my Win10 Home version, is it not available in this version?

Comment: Oh, okay. I'm not sure what registry entry needs to be changed...

Comment: Enable the group policy editor see relevant question with detailed answer

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1018145/windows-starter-edition-home-and-home-premium-do-not-include-gpedit-how-do-i-i