# How to turn on "only elevate executables that are signed and validated" setting

Tags: windows, windows-10, security, uac

I'm running Windows 10 Home, and I want to make sure that unsigned executables don't run (or at least I get a popup making sure that I want to run them).

I found [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/user-account-control-only-elevate-executables-that-are-signed-and-validated) page, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to enable this.

It gives me a location to the setting:

`Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\Security Options`

But that's not an absolute path. From where do I follow that path? Is this only available to Windows 10 Pro installs perhaps? Is this already enabled?

My UAC settings are set to the max (see picture [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/windows-itpro-docs/issues/733)). Is that enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is that enough?

It absolutely is not enough.  The default setting for this particular group policy is set to **disabled**, changing the UAC settings, does not **enable** the policy in question.

> Is this only available to Windows 10 Pro installs perhaps? Is this
>   already enabled?

You can only edit the group policy, through the group policy editor, on Windows 10 Professional and/or Windows Server.  It is possible to manually add the [group policy editor (gpedit) to Windows 10 Home](https://superuser.com/questions/1018145/windows-starter-edition-home-and-home-premium-do-not-include-gpedit-how-do-i-i/1018146#1018146).

The group policy you want to enable is: `User Account Control: Only elevate executables that are signed and validated` and by default it is disabled.

Of course, the simplest approach only requires editing the following registry key.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\ValidateAdminCodeSignatures
```

You will have to set the value from Disabled with a value of **0** to Enabled **1**.

### Sources

- [User Account Control Group Policy and registry key settings](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/user-account-control/user-account-control-group-policy-and-registry-key-settings#registry-key-settings)
- [User Account Control: Only elevate executables that are signed and validated](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/user-account-control/user-account-control-group-policy-and-registry-key-settings#user-account-control-only-elevate-executables-that-are-signed-and-validated)

Comment: I see no evidence in the documentation, that this group policy, is only limited to editions of Windows with the group policy.  However, if that is the case, then your solution to your problem, is to upgrade to an eligible edition of Windows.  I am leaving this as a comment, since "upgrading to an eligible edition of Windows", isn't an acceptable answer to any question (in my opinion).

Comment: Brilliant. I think I'll just tweak the registry directly. Thanks!

Comment: By the way, if I create an application (`.exe`) and run it, will this setting get in the way? I suspect that it will. Second, if it does, will it also get in the way if I create a script that runs the `.exe` programmatically?

Comment: @pushkin - You should read what the policy does.  Your question is unrelated to the question you asked.  **Comments are not designed to ask additional questions.**  *If you are interested, if your application will work, make the change and test it yourself.*