# How to permanently delete Windows Defender in Windows 10 Home?

Tags: windows-10, windows-defender

I specifically insist on deleting it (perhaps, the whole C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Platform folder), because it eats a lot of system resources while being turned off through several regedit tweaks and inside the Security Center itself. A program called Unlocker did absolutely nothing. My Windows 10 version is Home, so I'm unable to use Group Policy Editor. I also tried to use PsExec, but it could not help me. Applying all kinds of Security properties did not work either.

**Edit**: thank you for your help, but the registry trick is blocked by the system. NoDefender website is not serving the app anymore, and I cannot find it in Google, web archive refuses to give me a snapshot. I will try to use my Ubuntu to rename the folder.

**Edit 2**: renaming the folder using Ubuntu worked like a charm

Comment: Microsoft is making this harder with each OS update, it is becoming an integral part of Windows. What use to work no longer does with the latest build as far as I know.

Comment: @Biswapriyo Its not an answer, it is a comment, take it or leave it!

Comment: [Windows Starter Edition, Home and Home Premium do not include gpedit, how do I install it?](https://superuser.com/a/1018146/337631) - shameless plug, I wrote the question and answer :)

Comment: @DavidPostill Sorry, but I tried to use gpedit in order to disable Cortana and tracking about 2 years ago - it was crashing