# I installed gpedit on windows 10 home

Tags: windows, gpedit

But I still can't find the gpedit.msc. I have the dlls, I can run the program, but I can't locate the msc and it's driving me nuts. All my google searches lead me back to questions about how to activate gpedit.

Just to reiterate: I have it. I can't find it. Syswow64 contains gpedit.dll, it contains various mscs, it doesn't seem to contain gpedit.msc. I can run gpedit from command line but I can't locate this file.

(I am trying to gain full control over my telemetry and update settings on a Home version, that's the motivation for bothering with gpedit at all)

Comment: Since we do not know exactly how you "installed" gpedit there is no way we can help.

Comment: I have done it in W7 with no issues, never tried 10 but will a bit later, see this  page....https://superuser.com/a/1018146/40928

Comment: The only reason I am flagging this question as a duplicate is because, the answer to the duplicate has been confirmed to work with Windows 10 Home, thus if the solution is followed exactly your problem should resolve itself.

Comment: What do you get if you type `where gpedit` (into a Command Prompt)?  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.