# Windows 10 Home (no Group Policy Editor) unable to use finger print scanner with Windows Hello

Tags: windows-10, fingerprint, windows-hello

I've searched the Internet (and this site) for how to enable the fingerprint scanner on my HP Envy 15 laptop.

I got this laptop cheap, and it only came with Windows 8.1 Home, which I upgraded to Windows 10. Up until the last forced Windows 10 upgrade (GRRRRR), the fingerprint scanner was working perfectly with HP's SimplePass software. According to HP, Windows Hello has replaced SimplePass, but the FingerPrint option in "Sign-In Options" is disabled.

Every "solution" for this issue that I can find has been for Windows 10 Pro/Enterprise, and involves changing Group Policy settings. Windows 10 Home does not have a Group Policy Editor, so none of those solutions will work.

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling the driver for the reader, and updating to the latest drivers, but the Fingerprint option is still disabled.

Was there really that big of an oversight, and they've completely abandoned Windows Home users with fingerprint readers, or is there some other solution?

Comment: I'm not sure about this finger print scanner specifically, but check out [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1018145/windows-starter-edition-home-and-home-premium-do-not-include-gpedit-how-do-i-i) about installing gpedit on Windows Home edition. You might be able to resolve your issue with one of the earlier fixes you read about once you have gpedit available.

Comment: try to download the gpedit for the windows 10 home, and then try those solutions https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/How+to+get+gpedit+on+windows+10+Home/102025