# Microsoft asking to change password - cannot disable using lusrmgr.msc

Tags: windows-10

On Windows 10 Home, I want to permanently disable the archaic policy of periodic forced password changes. However, the [standard technique](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/i-dont-want-to-change-my-password/367927e5-c216-4cfb-a25c-b4d69be601b3?page=1) doesn't seem to be working for me as I end up with a screen saying the [Local Users and Groups snapin is unavailable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIJlN.png). Is there a workaround?

Comment: And when you follow the instructions and go to the user accounts tool in the control panel... what happens then?

Comment: Local users on Windows 10 Home and Windows 10 Professional are not required to change their password even if they are linked to a Microsoft account.  I have had the same password for my local account for over 10 years (to clarify I have upgraded the same installation through Windows 7, Windows 8, Windows 8.1, Windows 8.1 Update, Windows 10 (1507,1511,1607,1703,1709,1803,1809,1903).  If you are being asked to change your password it's because your machine has been configured that way (i.e. it's not default behavior).  My local account has been linked to my MS since Windows 8 RTM (day 1).

Comment: The real work around is to change the group policy either through the registry or use the [group policy editor](https://superuser.com/questions/1018145/windows-starter-edition-home-and-home-premium-do-not-include-gpedit-how-do-i-i)

Comment: I don't think Home version has gpedit?

Comment: @RobertLongson I checked that as well but it's unclear to me how anything on that page can help. There's just some account and credential management stuff.

Comment: Whoever downvoted, could you please explain why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft has very carefully omitted in Windows Home all the GUI elements for
managing user accounts attributes such as password expiration time.

One method is left, using the Command Prompt (cmd) that is run as Administrator.

Enter the command:

```
 wmic UserAccount where Name='USER-NAME' set PasswordExpires=False
```

If this works correctly, you will get the acknowledgement:

> Updating property(s) of
>   '\DESKTOP-8SEHR4O\ROOT\CIMV2:Win32_UserAccount.Domain="COMPUTER-NAME",Name="USER-NAME"'
>   Property(s) update successful.