# How to change the default setting of the Shut Down Windows dialog (Alt-F4)?

Tags: windows-10, shutdown, windows-10-v1803, windows-10-v1903

After a recent Windows update, the default option (when I press `Alt-F4`) in the *Shut Down Windows* dialog in Windows 10 has changed on my laptop:

[image: Shut Down Dialog in Windows 10]

The default option is now **Switch user**. Previously it was what I wanted: **Shut down**.

How can I restore **Shut down** as the default?<sup>1</sup>

Windows version: Windows 10 Home<sup>2</sup>

<sub>1. To avoid a catastrophic mistake, I would prefer not to edit the registry.</sub>

<sub>2. When I entered the question, the build was v1803. While processing [the accepted answer](https://superuser.com/a/1471676/40592), I rebooted Windows and it updated to v1903.</sub>

Comment: You will have to edit the registry or use software on this page....https://winaero.com/blog/set-default-action-shutdown-dialog-windows-10/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The displayed default action is set in :
*Power Options > Choose what the power buttons do > When I press the power button*.

Set the options of "On battery" and "Plugged in" both to "Shut down".
This should also change the default action.

---

An alternative solution for Windows versions Pro and above (not Home)
is to :

- Start the Local Group Policy Editor (`gpedit.msc`)
- Expand
  *User Configuration > Administrative Templates > Start Menu and Taskbar*
- Double-click on *Change Start Menu power button* policy to edit it
- Set the policy to "Enabled" and then the action to "Shut Down"
- Click OK and reboot.

---

For the poster, this was still not enough.

So we checked Windows integrity by running
[sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).
This, together with a Windows Update and some reboots, finally made this
setting stick.

Answer (score 0):

> To avoid a catastrophic mistake, I would prefer not to edit the registry.

Unless you are careless it is not possible to make a catastrophic mistake in this case.  Since you are using Windows 10 Home modifying the value in the registry is the only way to make this change since you are unable to use the group policy editor.  Any solution described in this answer requires you to be an Administrator on the machine.

> After a recent Windows update, the default option in the Shut Down
> Windows dialog in Windows 10 has changed on my laptop to `Switch user`
> previously it was `Shut Down`
>
> How can I restore Shut down as the default?

Within Registry Editor navigate to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced` and modify the **Start_PowerButtonAction** value to **0x2** (i.e. 00000002) from **0x100** (i.e. 00000100).  This will change the default behavior for the current user profile.

If you want to change the default behavior for all users on the machine modify the **PowerButtonAction** key  to **0x2** (i.e. 00000002) at the following locations:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer
```

Source: [How to Change Default Action of Shut Down Windows Dialog in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/137670-change-default-action-shut-down-windows-dialog-windows-10-a.html)

This can also be solved by using the group policy editor.  Withing the group policy editor you need to navigated to `Users Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Start Menu and Taskbar -> Change Start Menu power button`

> [image]

You must **Enable** and select the desired action of the button, the modification of this policy, requires a system reboot.

> [image]

Since you are running Windows 10 Home, you will have to install gpedit, which is indeed possible.

[Windows Starter Edition, Home and Home Premium do not include gpedit, how do I install it?](https://superuser.com/questions/1018145/windows-starter-edition-home-and-home-premium-do-not-include-gpedit-how-do-i-i)

Answer (score 0):

Pretty late to the party, but there might still be people reading this. It's happened to me two or three times in the past, and i'm pretty sure the cause is Windows Update. Before going to change registries or doing other extreme/complicated things, try the Update and Shut Down option from the "usual" power settings (the one in Start Menu). Now it might or might not work for you, but it did solve it everytime for me, and it might be a quick fix worth trying (unless you really don't want to update and shut down ‍♂️).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).