# Is it possible to add a Win10 Pro registry key to Home edition?

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, windows-update, group-policy

Specifically, `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\Internet Communication Management\Internet Communication`.

Apparently it's a Pro edition key used for editing a group policy, but can I add it to Home edition (version 1903)?

Thank you.

*edit: Moab helpfully pointed out that instead of adding *one* group-policy-editable key to the registry, it's possible to add the entire GPO functionality to Home edition. If/when I try this I'll update this question. The bigger question (and its answer) are linked in his comment below.

**edit^2: I was able to activate the group policy editor using the instructions in this link: https://www.techspot.com/guides/1719-group-policy-editor-windows-home/. I'm still waiting to see if automatic updates were truly disabled, or, like @Ramhound says, Windows won't honor my changes.

Comment: It entirely depends on which editions the policy is appliciable to.  While only Windows 10 Professional has the local group policy editor, certain polciies can be enabled on Windows 10 Home, while other polciies are ignored (i.e. Window Update deferment policies). **Since that particular key manages several polciies you will have to specify which policy specifically you are trying to set.**  A proper researched, detailed, accurate answer cannot be submitted without knowing which policy you want to set on Windows 10 Home.

Comment: https://www.ghacks.net/2019/01/07/how-to-enable-gpedit-msc-group-policy-on-windows-10-home-devices/

Comment: or an easier way....https://www.itechtics.com/easily-enable-group-policy-editor-gpedit-msc-in-windows-10-home-edition/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows Starter Edition, Home and Home Premium do not include gpedit, how do I install it?](https://superuser.com/questions/1018145/windows-starter-edition-home-and-home-premium-do-not-include-gpedit-how-do-i-i)

Comment: @Ramhound this is indeed a Windows Update deferment policy... or rather, a workaround I found on a couple sites. I planned to set `DisableWindowsUpdateAccess` in the Internet Communication key to `1`.

Comment: @Moab I wouldn't have thought simply adding the group policy functionality would have been possible... why would Home users ever pay money to upgrade to Pro? Convenience? I might try this if I have another automatic update debacle. Thank you very much.

Comment: @LukeMcPuke See the chart on this page for the advantages of Pro....https://www.zdnet.com/article/do-you-need-more-than-windows-7-home-premium/

Comment: @LukeMcPuke - Windows 10 Home will not honor any policy surrounding Windows Update.  Even if you manually configure it in the registry.