# Why do I have gpedit.msc files on a Windows 10 home edition?

Tags: windows-10, gpedit

I am running a Windows 10 home edition and I found several gpedit.msc files in my computer, Why are they there? Windows 10 home doesn't even come with the Group Policy Editor.

[image]

Note: Running gpedit.msc in a Run Window reports "Cannot find gpedit.msc"

Comment: Did you maybe upgrade to Windows 10 from another version of windows, such as windows 7?

Comment: @LPChip No, I didn't.

Comment: The WinSxS folder you see those files in is actually the folder that Windows uses to reinstall and upgrade from. For example, with Windows 10, it is possible to upgrade directly from Home to Pro with just a new license key. Those files specific to Pro will then be pulled from that folder and installed on your machine. As it stands now, they are not usable by your machine.

Comment: Just because they are in the winsxs folder does not mean that it is part of Home edition, its there for upgrade purposes, like if you upgrade to Pro.

Comment: You can [install gpedit](https://superuser.com/questions/1018145/windows-starter-edition-home-and-home-premium-do-not-include-gpedit-how-do-i-i) if you want ...